# Finding derived object in a vector of base

Tags: c++, oop, casting, polymorphism, rtti

I found the following code in some project:

```cpp
std::vector<Base*> objs_;

template <class TDerived>
T* Get() {
  auto objIt = std::find_if(objs_.cbegin(), objs_.cend(), [](Base* it) {
    return typeid(TDerived).name() == typeid(*it).name();
  });
  return objIt == objs_.cend() ? nullptr : *objIt;
}
```

I'm trying to figure out, is using `typeid` a good choice?
Because C++ has `dynamic_cast`, for example:

```cpp
template <class TDerived>
T* Get() {
  auto objIt = std::find_if(objs_.cbegin(), objs_.cend(), [](Base* it) {
    return dynamic_cast<T*>(it) != nullptr;
  });
  return objIt == objs_.cend() ? nullptr : *objIt;
}
```

I know that there is a semantic difference between the solutions above, because `dynamic_cast` will complain about `TDerived` inheritor also, but that's ok, all used `TDerived` are `final`.

Is `typeid` a good choice, or is `dynamic_cast` better, or is there some better solution for it?

Comment: `typeid` is not required to be unique, so hardly ever a good choice. On the other hand, *why* do you need to find the exact type?  Could not a virtual function in Base be more helpful?

Comment: No, `typeid` is not a good choice. Neither is `dynamic_cast`. This entire approach should be scrapped and rewritten from scratch, using `unique_ptr` or `shared_ptr` and virtual methods. Avoid writing code that looks like what was found in "some project".

Comment: Obvious question: why does the code need to identify objects by their type?  As @BoP says, this is usually easy to avoid (and therefore should be).

Comment: That's not my code, thats why I've asked it.
As for "why do you need to find the exact type", I'll try to say what I understood from the code.

The author adds some derived objects in the collection and then checks if it contains an object of some type. If yes, he calls some virtual function, otherwise, doesnt.

Comment: @excommunicado The 'what type is this object' test can easily be avoided then.  Just add a 'do nothing' virtual function to the base class and call it regardless.  I point this out to demonstrate my claim that testing the type of a (polymorphic) object is rarely, if ever, necessary.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, [`typeid`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/typeid) is not a good idea at all, because subtyping one of the involved types would require to enrich the parts where  `typeid` is checked. This is agains the [open/closed principle](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open%E2%80%93closed_principle).

By the way, there are a lot of subtle issues with `typeid`, e.g. there's no standardization of the type names returned, and moreover, as pointed out on cppreference:

> There is no guarantee that the same std::type_info instance will be referred to by all evaluations of the typeid expression on the same type, although they would compare equal, std::type_info::hash_code of those type_info objects would be identical, as would be their std::type_index.

The use of `dynamic_cast`  is slightly better, because it may allow to respect the open/closed principle regarding if you don't add a new type. But if you do,  you're again bound to enrich the code. Moreover, `dynamic_cast` requires the using class/function to know about a lot about of the used classes. This may weaken [encapsulation](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Encapsulation_(computer_programming)) and create hidden coupling (i.e you can no longer change the used classes as you want, because you light break some assumptions)

The best approach is to rewrite the code in a polymorphic way. The C++ core guidelines remind in this regard that [virtual functions should be preferred to casting](https://isocpp.github.io/CppCoreGuidelines/CppCoreGuidelines#Rh-use-virtual). More generally, the approach should use the [tell don't ask principle](https://martinfowler.com/bliki/TellDontAsk.html), and let polymorphic code do what it has to do. Or opt for the [visitor pattern](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visitor_pattern).

Answer (score 2):

You can't compare the names, because they don't have to have the same pointer values for the same types. For example, `typeid(TDerived).name() == typeid(TDerived).name()` can be false.

You should be comparing the typeids directly instead with [`std::type_info::operator==`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/type_info/operator_cmp):

```cpp
    return typeid(TDerived) == typeid(*it);
```

As for whether this is better than the `dynamic_cast`, it depends. For a final class as you've mentioned, there is no difference semantically. I would think comparing `typeid`s makes your intentions clearer.